# Equivilent Loadcontrol

Tags: vb.net, ascx

I have a .ascx file that I can load in no problem using

```
<uc1:EL ID="EL1" BusinessID="8" runat="server" />
```

Where BusinessID is a Public Property.

```
Public Property BusinessID As Integer
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _BusinessID = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return _BusinessID
    End Get
End Property
```

I may need to load this ascx file several times into a placeholder with different BusinessID variable values.

What is the equivalent LoadControl way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create an instance of the user control, then get a handle on the place holder.  Then you can add one to the other.  Example:

```
 'get place holder
 Dim getPh As New PlaceHolder
 getPh = CType(Me.FindControl("myPlaceHolder"), PlaceHolder)

 'get user controls    
 Dim newUserControl As New user_controls_myControlName
 newUserControl = CType(LoadControl("~/user_controls/myControlName.ascx"), user_controls_myControlName)    

 getPh.Controls.Add(newPortlet)
```

Once you create an instance of the user control, you have access to all its properties, including BusinessID and you can assign it whatever you want.

Forgot one thing, you will need to add a reference in the client side code of your ascx file, like this:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/user_controls/myControlName.ascx"%>
```

Comment: Thanks for response but what is user_control_myControlName?

Comment: OK, I got it onto page using a declared variable. using the newUserControl.BusinessID = (number), whats the correct syntax?

Comment: user_control_myControlName is the name of the user control object.  You should see something like this format in Intellisence but with the name of your user control.  This example uses as user control called "myControlName".  FYI, sometimes, after adding a new reference, intellisence will not work properly until you clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Do you mean? Portals_0_Open_BusinessDirectory_EnhancedListing

Comment: Perfect, gotya!! That was the rebuild that didnt make sense. Thank you so much